# Why do the Canadian Liberals not designate the IRGC as a terrorist organization?

Tags: parliament, terrorism, canada

The Conservative Party of Canada (official opposition) has continuously called the Liberals (ruling party) to designate the [IRGC (Iran’s Revolutionary Guard Corps)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Revolutionary_Guard_Corps) as a terrorist organization.

The United States have designated them as such in [2019](https://www.state.gov/foreign-terrorist-organizations/).

The Liberals seem to have no answer about why they do not do the same.

[Canada and Iran have no diplomatic relations since 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93Iran_relations) while maintaining relationships with countries which have a negative view of the IRGC, such as the US and Israel.

What could be the reason behind not wanting to apply the designation?

Comment: Same as most of Europe not designating IRGC as such, I guess. Only Sweden does so (in Europe) on a quick check.

Comment: What benefit would Canada get from calling them a terrorist organization? It is mostly a statement saying we will not talk to you, no interest in any diplomacy whatsoever.

Comment: @quarague Optics. The current situation is that the conservatives are essentially implying that the liberals tacitly support terrorists and the liberals dont help themselves by giving non-answers in response.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Why do the Canadian Liberals not designate the IRGC as a terrorist organization?

Are we talking individuals here?  Because the Canadian government is lead by "liberals" and they do recognize IRGC as a terrorist Organization.

October 7, 2022, Canada announced it intends to pursue a terrorist designation for the IRGC under its Immigration and Refugee Protection Act.

> **[Canada barring entry to IRGC members in new Iran sanctions push](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2022/10/7/canada-barring-entry-to-irgc-members-in-new-iran-sanctions-push)**
>
> Canadian Prime Minister Justin Trudeau has announced plans to bar about 10,000 members of Iran’s Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (IRGC) from entering Canada, as international pressure on Tehran builds amid ongoing anti-government protests.
> During a news conference on Friday, Trudeau said the top 50 percent of the IRGC’s leadership would get lifetime entry bans under new penalties imposed through Canada’s Immigration and Refugee Protection Act.

> **[Canada Amends Iranian Sanctions Regulations: 6 Individuals Targeted](https://sanctionsnews.bakermckenzie.com/canada-amends-iranian-sanctions-regulations-6-individuals-targeted/)**
>
> Sept 20, 2023
>
> Other individuals listed include the senior commander of the Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (IRGC) in Iran’s Kurdish provinces and the head of the Iranian Parliament’s national security and affairs committee. These sanctions are imposed in coordination with the European Union, the United Kingdom and the United States.

The IRGC is currently sanctioned under **[Canada's Special Economic Measures Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-2010-165/fulltext.html)** (SEMA).

> - 36  IRGC Air Force (and IRGC Air Force Missile Command)
> - 37  IRGC Logistics and Procurement
> - 38  IRGC Missile Command
> - 39  IRGC Navy
> - 136 Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (also known as IRGC, Army of the - Guardians of the Islamic Revolution, Iranian Revolutionary Guards, IRG and Sepah-e Pasdaran-e Enghelab-e Eslami)
> - The Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps’ (IRGC) Cyber Defense Command